# Cause of this error: No List matches the given query

Tags: python, html, django, watch

The user can add that product to the watch list by clicking on the add button, and then the add button will change to Rimo. And this time by clicking this button, the product will be removed from the list.
There should be a link on the main page that by clicking on it, all the products in the watch list will be displayed, and by clicking on the detail button, you can see the details of the product, and by clicking on the remove button, you can remove them from the list.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class List(models.Model):
    choice = (
        ('d', 'Dark'),
        ('s', 'Sweet'),
    )
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField()  
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64)      
    first_bid = models.IntegerField()  
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="img/", null=True)      
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=228, default = None, blank = True, null = 
             True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices= choice)
    active_bool = models.BooleanField(default = True)

class Watchlist(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    watch_list = models.ForeignKey(List, on_deleted= 
                models.CASCADE)
```

views.py:

```
def product_detail(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(List, pk=product_id)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(product=product)

    if request.method == 'POST':
    
        # comment
        if 'comment' in request.POST:
            user = request.user
            if user.is_authenticated:
                content = request.POST.get('content')
                comment = Comment(product=product, user=user, content=content)
                comment.save()
    

    context = {
        'product': product,
        'comments': comments, 
       }

    return render(request, 'auctions/product_detail.html', context)



 @login_required(login_url="login")
 def watchlist(request, username):
     products = Watchlist.objects.filter(user = username)
     return render(request, 'auctions/watchlist.html', 
           {'products': products})


 @login_required(login_url="login")
 def add(request, productid):
     #watch = Watchlist.objects.filter(user = 
              #request.user.username)
      watchlist_product = get_object_or_404(Watchlist, 
                          pk=productid)

     for items in watchlist_product:
        if int(items.watch_list.id) == int(productid):
            return watchlist(request, request.user.username)
    
    product = get_object_or_404(List, 
               pk=watchlist_product.watch_list)
   new_watch = Watchlist(product, user = request.user.username)
   new_watch.save()
   messages.success(request, "Item added to watchlist")
   return product_detail(request, productid)




@login_required(login_url="login")
def remove(request, pid):
    #remove_id = request.GET[""]
    list_ = Watchlist.objects.get(pk = pid)
    messages.success(request, f"{list_.watch_list.title} is 
         deleted from your watchlist.")
    list_.delete()
    return redirect("index")
```

product_deyail.html(Only the parts related to the question):

```
    <form method= "get" action = "{% url 'add' product.id %}">
    
        <button type = "submit" value = "{{ product.id }}"  name 
         = "productid" >Add to Watchlist</button>
    </form>
```

watchlist.html:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}
{% block body %}

    {% if products %}
        {% for product in products %}
            <img src= {{ product.image.url }} alt = " 
               {{product.title}}"><br>
            <a><a>Product:</a>{{ product.title }}</a><br>
            <a><a>Category: </a>{{ product.category }}</a><br>
            <a><a>Frist Bid: </a> {{ product.first_bid }} $ </a> 
                  <br>
        

            <a href="{% url 'product_detail' product.id %}">View 
                Product</a>

            <form action="{% url 'remove' product.id %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit">Remove</button>
            </form>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <p>No products in watchlist</p>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

layout.html(Only the parts related to the question & To display the linked name):

```
<ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">Active Listings</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'watchlist' 
                  user.username %}">My WatchList</a>
        </li>


        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
            </li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
```

urls.py:

```
path('watchlist/<str:username>', views.watchlist, 
      name='watchlist'),
path('add/<int:productid>', views.add, name='add'),
path('remove/<int:pid>', views.remove, name='remove'),
```

error:
Reverse for 'product_detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['product_detail/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/\Z']

watchlist.html:

```
<a href="{% url 'product_detail' product_id %}">View Product</a>
```

Comment: @raphael Thanks. The first way gives this error for the last line of the watchlist function. Reverse for 'product_detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['product_detail/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your initial error is that `<form method= "get" action = "{% url 'add' %}">` is creating a url with the parameter `productid`, which your path, `path('add/', views.add, name='add')`, does not handle.

You *could* change it to

`path('add/<int:productid>', views.add, name='add')`

and change the view to

`def add(request, productid):`

Then you wouldn't need the `product_id = request.POST.get('productid', False)`.

The reason you get

`"Reverse for 'product_detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['product_detail/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']"`

is most likely because the line

`<button type = "submit" value = {{ product.id }}  name = "productid" >Add to Watchlist</button>`

has the value unquoted, so it may not read it, thus sending an empty string back.

Change it to

`<button type = "submit" value = "{{ product.id }}"  name = "productid" >Add to Watchlist</button>`

Comment: Thank you, it works now, but I have to delete these two lines from the watchlist.html file so that it will be OK, otherwise it will get this error.

(<a href="{% url 'product_detail' item.id %}">View Product</a>).
 <form action="{% url 'remove' pid %}" method="post">)



(Reverse for
'remove' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['remove/(?P<pid>[0-9]+)\\Z'])


Before that, I should say that the Remo function was also getting the same error as the Add function, and I added the same changes that I added for Add to Remo.

Comment: Also, after adding to the list, the button does not change to Remo, and the Remo button in the watch list also gives the same error.

Comment: @zahrashokrizadeh I have to see your updated watchlist.html, urls.py and views.py to troubleshoot.  But initially, I see `{% for product in products %}`, and yet you use `item.id`.

Comment: Because it didn't work, I replaced the product with an item to see if it would work.
I updated the question with new codes. Please check.

Comment: @zahrashokrizadeh the variables you have available to you in the html template are the ones sent by your views.py, which in this case is `products`.  When you loop using `{% for product in products %}` the only variable you have available to you is `product`, so `product.id`, or `product.title`, etc...  You do *not* have other variables like `item` or `pid` so they are null, and that's the root of all your errors.  Replace `item.id` with `product.id`.  Replace `pid` with `product.id` and see if that helps.

Comment: Yessssss, thanks so much.
It works now.
Only the watch list button on the product page does not change to Remo after the product is added to the list, and this product information is not displayed.
You can see the changes I made in the question.

Comment: And when I click on the product details link, it gives this error: Page not found (404)
No listings match the given query.
Request method: GET
Request address: http://127.0.0.1:8000/product_detail/3/
Submitted by: auctions.views.product_detail

Comment: Did you remove the path, `path("product_detail/<int:product_id>/", views.product_detail, name="product_detail"),`?

Comment: This is written in the URL file: path("product_detail/<int:product_id>/", views.product_detail, name="product_detail")


In the question, I wrote only the path related to the watch list.

Comment: @zahrashokrizadeh you are sending `products = Watchlist.objects.filter(user = username)` to the watchlist.html, so they are `Watchlist` objects with `Watchlist` id's.  But the line `product = get_object_or_404(List, pk=product_id)` is trying to match up a `List` object with the id of the `Watchlist` found.  It doesn't find it, and thus your error.  Try getting the `Watchlist` object first: `watchlist_product = get_object_or_404(Watchlist, pk=product_id)` then find the correct `Product` by doing `product = get_object_or_404(List, pk=watchist_product.watch_list)`.

Comment: With these changes, when clicking on the add button, it gives this error:
`Page not found (404)
No Watchlist matches the given query.
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/add/1?productid=1
Raised by: auctions.views.add`

You can see the changes in the code

Comment: Try replacing `<button type = "submit" value="{{ product.id }}"  name ="productid" >Add to Watchlist</button>` with `<button type = "submit" >Add to Watchlist</button>` .  I do not think I can help further here, but if you have a Github with all the code, I can try run it myself if this doesn't work.

Comment: It shows the same error again and says page not found.
Thanks so much for taking the time to answer. I don't have the conditions to use GitHub. Is it possible to send you the zipped file?

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'add' %}">  <button type="submit" value="{{ product.id }}" name="productid">Add to  Watchlist</button> </form>
```

or

product_id = request.GET.get('productid', False)

Comment: In the first case, it gives this error: Forbidden (403).
CSRF verification failed. The request was cancelled.


 And in the second case this: Cannot parse keyword query as dict...File "C:\Users\N\Desktop\work on it\commerce\auctions\views.py", line 144, in add
    new_watch = get_object_or_404 ( watchList , context )

Comment: csrf_token must be added to the form or meta tag

<form method="post" action="{% url 'add' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" value="{{ product.id }}" name="productid">Add to  Watchlist</button>
</form>

Comment: It doesn't work and gives the same error

Comment: this one: Page not found (404)